# Fast unique index based on outer conditions in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Suppose I have two lists of indices `index1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `index2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and a `numpy` array `x=array([1.3876, -0.573, -1.765, 1.2202, -1.6507, -0.653, 0.9196, 0.0935])` that generates `index2`. I would like to keep unique indices in both index lists that retain the maximum values from `x`. For example, if index in `index1` is duplicated, e.g., two `1`, I will keep only one `1` for `index1` and index in `index2` having highest value in `x`, i.e., `0` for `index2` as `x[0] > x[1]` with both `0` and `1` in `index2` mapped to the two `1` in `index1`.

I have millions of lists for checking. After trying my best to reduce the number of comparisons, I found the implementation for uniqueness was the most time spent. My current implementation is:

```
import numpy as np
import collections
index1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
index2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = np.array([1.3876, -0.573, -1.765, 1.2202, -1.6507, -0.653, 0.9196, 0.0935])

# I put the following as a function in my codes with above as inputs, e.g., index1, index2 = unique_index(index1, index2, x)
idx = collections.defaultdict()
for i, j in zip(index1, index2):
    if i not in idx or x[j] > x[idx[i]]:
        idx[i] = j
index1, index2 = zip(*idx.items())
# return index1=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), index2=(0, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Any faster way?

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that:

- indices are always integers between 0 and `len(x)-1` included;
- there is a lot of values (i.e. at least thousands of values);
- the output order of `index1` does not matter as long as the relation between `index1` and `index2` is preserved.

You can use an **array to store the already seen values** and optimize the algorithm with **Numba** and **vectorized Numpy operations**. Here is how:

```py
from numba import njit
from numba.types import UniTuple, int_ as dint, float64

# Add the parameter parallel=True, only if arrays are known to be huge (i.e > 1e6)
@njit(UniTuple(dint[:],2)(dint[:],dint[:],float64[:]))
def fast_unique_index(index1, index2, x):
    size = len(index1)
    idx = np.full(size, -1)
    for k in range(size):
        i, j = index1[k], index2[k]
        if idx[i] < 0 or x[j] > x[idx[i]]:
            idx[i] = j
    filledIdx = idx >= 0
    return (np.where(filledIdx)[0], idx[filledIdx])
```

On my machine, this function is **32 times faster** than the reference implementation with the following configuration:

```py
s = 330_000
# Randomized array
index1 = np.random.randint(s, size=s)
index2 = np.random.randint(s, size=s)
x = np.random.rand(s)
```

Here are the raw results:

```
Reference version:  0.192492 seconds
Proposed version:   0.005909 seconds
```

---

If the lists are small (<100), there is not much you can do. You can still use the array-based indexing trick from the above solution to speed up a bit the implementation since Python `dict` should be slower than lists (due to hashing). Alternatively, you can try to use Cython to slightly speed up the code.

Comment: Thanks. My lists generally have <100 indices. After testing this implementation using my 330k lists, it's two times slower than my version. I think this implementation requires one more operation like `np.array(index1)[filledIdx]` if `index1` is not a list like `list(range(max(index1)))`.

Comment: I edited the answer to add more information about results and small lists. For the speed on 330k lists, this is strange since I get a speed a of x32 on random array of such size. I gave additional details so you can reproduce that. Note that the first call to the function could be slower if the array types are not the one specified in the code because the JIT needs to recompile the code on the fly. Regarding `np.array(index1)[filledIdx]`, I don't know since results are identical to your code once put in a dict not to take into account the order (on random data).

Comment: Thanks. I think you misunderstood the lists. In my data, the number of indices (/values/elements) in each list is <100. I have > 330k such kind of lists for comparisons. After `%prun` in Jupyter notebook, my implementation ("Reference version") is faster, and lots of time is spent for `numpy.ufunc.reduce` in your implementation which may be because of involving too many numpy array indexing in so many uniqueness operations (or function calls) comparing to that using a single large list.